# Запрос на последнюю строчку определенного столбца

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pymysql

В классе **TestWindow** есть счетчик который отправляет результат в таблицу в колонку Результат. В классе **EndTestWindow** пишу запрос на выдачу результата из БД но выдается только 1 вместо реального результата. Во втором варианте добавил **self.cursor.fetchall()** Теперь постоянно пишет Результат': 'None' хотя на самом деле это не так

```
SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY Результат DESC LIMIT 1
```

Такой запрос пишет ошибку на =%s

```
SELECT * FROM students WHERE Результат =%s
```

**TestWindow**

```
class TestWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_Test):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.connection = pymysql.connect(
            host=host,
            port=3306,
            user=user,
            password=password,
            database=db_name,
            cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
        )
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()


        self.pushButtonEndTest.clicked.connect(self.openEndTestWindow)
        self.pushButtonEndTest.clicked.connect(self.Resylt)


    def Resylt(self):
        self.res = 0
        if self.comboBox.currentIndex() == self.kk_1:
            self.res = self.res+1
        if self.comboBox_2.currentIndex() == self.kk_2:
            self.res = self.res+1
        if self.comboBox_3.currentIndex() == self.kk_3:
                self.res = self.res+1
        if self.comboBox_4.currentIndex() == self.kk_4:
                self.res = self.res+1
        if self.comboBox_5.currentIndex() == self.kk_5:
                self.res = self.res+1
        print("Количество верных ответов - " + str(self.res))
        self.cursor.execute(f"UPDATE students SET Результат = '{self.res}' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
        self.connection.commit()


    def openEndTestWindow(self):
        self.EndTest = EndTestWindow()
        self.close()
        self.EndTest.show()
```

**EndTestWindow**

```
class EndTestWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_EndTest):
    def __init__(self):
        super(EndTestWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.connection = pymysql.connect(
            host=host,
            port=3306,
            user=user,
            password=password,
            database=db_name,
            cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
        )
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        # ozenka = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM students WHERE Результат =%s")
        ozenka = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
        self.connection.commit()
        self.label_2.setText("Ваша оценка "+ (str(ozenka))  + " из 5")


        self.Button_startMain.clicked.connect(self.openToMain)

    def openToMain(self):
        self.close()
        w.show()
```

**Второй вариант EndTestWindow**

```
class EndTestWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_EndTest):
    def __init__(self):
        super(EndTestWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.connection = pymysql.connect(
            host=host,
            port=3306,
            user=user,
            password=password,
            database=db_name,
            cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
        )
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
        self.cursor.execute("SELECT Результат FROM students ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
        # ozenka = self.cursor.execute("SELECT Результат FROM students ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
        ozenka = self.cursor.fetchall()
        self.connection.commit()
        self.label_2.setText("Ваша оценка "+ (str(ozenka))  + " из 5")
        # ozenka = self.cursor.execute("SELECT Результат FROM students ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
        # # ozenka = self.cursor.execute("SELECT Результат FROM students ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1")
        
        # self.connection.commit()
        # self.label_2.setText("Ваша оценка "+ (str(ozenka))  + " из 5")


        self.Button_startMain.clicked.connect(self.openToMain)

    def openToMain(self):
        self.close()
        w.show()
```

[image: Результат 1го EndTestWindow]

[image: Результат 2го EndTestWindow]

Comment: зачем ставить теги #python #mysql #pymysql, если всё из вышеперечисленного здесь отсутствует? И создайте, пожалуйста, минимально воспроизводимый пример

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо сортировать по столбцу `id`, чтобы последний элемент стал первым. Вот так должно сработать:

```
SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: В Sql ваш запрос работает выдает всю строчку, а мне нужно чтобы выдавал определенную строчку и строку

Comment: Может, вы имели ввиду определённый столбец последней строки? Тогда так: ```SELECT `Результат` FROM students ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1```

Comment: Теперь 2 раза выдается слово Результат, запросы так-то правильные, но питон не хочет его выводить

Comment: А что у вас выводится, если сделать `print(ozenka)` после строки `ozenka = self.cursor.fetchall()` во втором варианте EndTestWindow?

Comment: В вопросе есть 2 скрина с результатами программы, 1й это EndTestWindow, а 2й скрин второй вариант EndTestWindow

Comment: @TigerShark, а точно) извиняюсь